# Indexes visible in Index Management, but cannot select in discovery

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

When we go to the page/path

```
/kibana/app/management/data/index_management/indices
```

we see that indexes have created.

The next step is to see them in discovery mode, but there we don't see the created indexes.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see you indices in discover you need to create a data view (aka index_pattern) in Kibana. You can follow this path to create a data view => `Kibana/Stack Management/Data View`

> I recommend you to create an index_pattern with regex like
> `index_name*`

Here is a screenshot for you.

[image]